# "configure" script of Autotools always consume all my 4GB RAM immediately and hang my computer

Tags: makefile, autotools, configure

Whenever I run the `configure` script of GNU-Autotools by running the `./configure` command. It consume all my RAM(4GB) very fast immediately during 5 second then hang my computer. I use Linux system and I test this problem with different GNU source packages and the result is same. You can see an example of running `configure` below:

I break the process by CTRL+C when the process reach to "checking for BSD- or MS-compatible name lister (nm)...".

My config.log: http://ashavahishta.persiangig.com/document/Text/config.log

```
$ ./configure

checking for a BSD-compatible install... 
/usr/bin/install -c 
checking whether build environment is sane... yes 
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... 
/bin/mkdir -p checking for gawk... gawk 
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes 
checking whether make supports nested variables... yes 
checking whether UID '1000' is supported by ustar format... yes 
checking whether GID '1000' is supported by ustar format... yes 
checking how to create a ustar tar archive... gnutar 
checking whether to enable maintainer-specific portions of Makefiles... yes 
checking whether make supports nested variables... (cached) yes 
checking for gcc... gcc checking whether the C compiler works... yes 
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out 
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... no 
checking for suffix of object files... o 
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes 
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes 
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed 
checking whether gcc understands -c and -o together... yes 
checking for style of include used by make... GNU 
checking dependency style of gcc... gcc3 
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... (cached) yes 
checking for special C compiler options needed for large files... no 
checking for _FILE_OFFSET_BITS value needed for large files... no 
checking for pkg-config... /usr/bin/pkg-config 
checking pkg-config is at least version 0.9.0... yes 
checking for gcc... gcc 
checking whether we are using the GNU Objective C compiler... yes 
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes 
checking dependency style of gcc... gcc3 
checking build system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu 
checking host system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu 
checking how to print strings... printf 
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /bin/sed 
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /bin/grep 
checking for egrep... /bin/grep -E 
checking for fgrep... /bin/grep -F 
checking for ld used by gcc... /usr/bin/ld 
checking if the linker (/usr/bin/ld) is GNU ld... yes 
checking for BSD- or MS-compatible name lister (nm)...
```

After all `checking`, Here Memory Finished and I break the Process by CTRL+C to Rescue My Computer.

Comment: The process consume all my RAM when reach to this line:  checking for BSD- or MS-compatible name lister (nm)...

Comment: This is not normal behavior for Autotools `configure` scripts on any platform, and especially not on Linux, so I am inclined to think that there is something very unusual about your computer's configuration contributing to the issue.  In any case, the log file that `configure` writes (config.log) may provide more detail about the command that causes the misbehavior.  This would be useful information, especially if you can confirm that the same command is responsible in different cases.

Comment: I break the process by CTRL+C when the process reach to "checking for BSD- or MS-compatible name lister (nm)...". This is my config.log:  http://ashavahishta.persiangig.com/document/Text/config.log

Comment: Now I findout that the problem is the "nm" and when I run this process alone I can see same problem again and it consumes all my RAM. I test the "gcc-nm-5" and "gcc-nm-8" and nothing didn't changed and the problem is still present!

Comment: Obviously, `nm` is not supposed to do that, and that explains the behavior of your `configure` scripts.  I don't think we're in a position here to help you troubleshoot this, however.  Google may be your friend in that, or perhaps someone over at Unix & Linux SE will recognize the issue.

Comment: Thank you Mr Bollinger for your help and attention. Now I try to remove and install binutils and dependencies again. It's really strange problem!

Comment: Now I find out that what was the problem! There was a circular link to nm file that try to run itself again and again and consumed all my RAM very fast.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I reinstalled the `binutils` to solve the problem with `nm` but nothing didn't changed then I removed `binutils` and  it's dependencies and I install it again and now everything works perfect.

I didn't find what was happened about `nm` but I just found that was the problem during configure process.

I hope this answer help other people too.